# Contacts back up app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts, database-backups

I want to make a contacts back up app for iPhone which will save all contacts details to a web server. What steps should I follow to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to the use the AddressBook Framework. Here is a reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

As far as actually backing up the data, you'll most likely want to have a php page which takes data, parses it, and then backs it up into a mySQL database.

Hope this helps!